# Flagging a series of no longer necessary comments

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

I have several times seen situations where there is a conversation in comments that is no longer necessary (e.g. "can you clarify x", "clarification", "you should ask x as a separate question", "okay, I've asked it separately and edited this question").

In this situation, is it appropriate to flag each of the comments as no longer necessary or should I only flag one and leave whoever is handling the flag to remove any others?  From looking around it seems that in some cases it might be appropriate to flag the question or answer and request that the comments be removed but is that still the case if there are valid comments among to out of date ones?

Comment: The linked Q&A is 6 years old. Does it still hold? Have moderator tools changed in that time?

Comment: Pretty much, @CrisLuengo but it's kinda different on a per-mod basis. I generally recommend a single flag on the post. If we made it possible for users to flag comments in bulk, it might be different but we don't and there's a rate limit on flagging so flagging a dozen comments can be annoying.

Comment: @Catija, but flagging a dozen comments gets me to the Marshall badge faster! :p

Comment: On SO a mod told me the cut-off is at 4 comments based on optimizing the number of clicks for the mod. For 5 or more comments I flag the post, 4 or less I flag the individual comments